# Does Google change Ctrl to Cmd if you are using a Mac?

Tags: text

In the two images below, you can see that Google displays `Ctrl` instead of `Cmd`.

https://docs.google.com/

[image: https://docs.google.com/]

http://goo.gl/

[image: http://goo.gl/]

If the user is using Mac (I only have Windows) does the interface change accordingly or does it remain as `Ctrl` instead of `Cmd`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, it did.[image]

[image]

Comment: Blast, beaten by three minutes. I can confirm that the US English versions of both those screenshots are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry to ask for so much, but could you check if that Cmd sign thing is a char or an image?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, it is a char: ⌘. I think all Mac fonts has it.